# Intentionally Fail Health Check using Route 53 AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, health-monitoring

I have a query as to whether what I want to achieve is doable, and if so, perhaps someone could give me some advice on how to achieve this.

So I have set up a health check on Route 53 for my server, and I have arranged so that if the health check fails, the user will be redirected to a static website I have set up at a backup site.

I also have a web scraper running regularly collecting data, and my question is, would their be a way to use the data I have collected, and depending on its value, either pass or fail the heath check, therefore determining what site the user would be diverted to.

I have discussed with AWS support and they have said that their policies and conditions are there by design, and long story short would not support what I am trying to achieve.

I'm a pretty novice programmer so I'm not sure if it's possible to work this, but this is my final hurdle so any advice or help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make up a filename.  Let's say `healthy.txt`.
- Put that file on your web server, in the HTML root.  It doesn't really matter what's in the file.
- Verify that if you go to your site and try to download it using a web browser, it works.
- Configure the Route 53 health check as HTTP and set the `Path` for the check to use `/healthy.txt`.

To make your server "unhealthy," just delete the file.  The Route 53 health checker will get a 404 error -- unhealthy.

To make the server "healthy" again, just re-create the file.